# How to store php sessions using memcached and unix socket

Tags: php, nginx, memcached, session, systemd

I am running Arch linux with systemd, nginx, and php with php-fpm.  I am trying (and failing) to configure memcached to store sessions using a unix socket.  I have memcached installed and active, however, I am unable to disable networking.  I added the following line to /etc/conf.d/memcached

```
MEMCACHED_ARGS="-s unix:///tmp/memcached.sock -a 666"
```

I also tried:

```
MEMCACHED_ARGS="-s /tmp/memcached.sock -a 666"
MEMCACHED_ARGS="-s unix:/tmp/memcached.sock -a 666"
```

when I restart memcached I always get:

```
memcached.service - Memcached Daemon
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled)
          Active: active (running) since Sat 2013-01-19 17:41:15 PST; 5min ago
        Main PID: 773 (memcached)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/memcached.service
                  └─773 /usr/bin/memcached -l 127.0.0.1
```

when I run php script with sessions php error log shows (not surprisingly):

```
[19-Jan-2013 16:46:45 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (unix:/tmp/memcached.sock) in Unknown on line 0
```

I also installed the php-memcached package but I don't what it does or how to get it going.  I uncommented the following line in /etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini:

```
extension=memcached.so
```

but that didn't change anything.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Memcached config.d

A file path is all that's needed for Memcached's unix socket.

```ini
MEMCACHED_ARGS="-s /tmp/memcached.sock -a 666"
```

You can confirm that Memcached is operating normally by running the `stats` command through the unix socket.

```bash
bash $> echo stats | nc -U /tmp/memcached.sock
# returns list of server statistics
```

### Configure PHP's session to use Memcached

Edit `php.ini`, or `/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini`, and add [session support](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php).

```ini
extension=memcached.so
session.save_handler="memcached"
session.save_path="/tmp/memcached.sock"
```

Restart services and verify php logs

Comment: info here is good. Thanks. I also had to put memcached config info into service file because config file wasn't getting read.  Furthermore I had to install php-memcached package per http://www.pontikis.net/blog/install-memcached-php-archlinux

Comment: Instead of making the file world-writable, you could also run memcached as the web server user (if possible).